# Why does Android randomly load the native library?

Tags: android, c++, load, android-native-library

I am studying the loading process of Android dynamic library by learning source code. In /bionic/linker/linker.cpp, I found that after getting the information of the dynamic library and its dependent libraries,  will put them into the “load_list”, then call the “shuffle” function to randomize it, and then load libraries in "load_list". I want to know what the purpose of randomization is.

The Android version I researched is 8.0.0_r4，and the randomized operation was added after October 2015, the previous version did not.

```cpp
1498static void shuffle(std::vector<LoadTask*>* v) {
1499  for (size_t i = 0, size = v->size(); i < size; ++i) {
1500    size_t n = size - i;
1501    size_t r = arc4random_uniform(n);
1502    std::swap((*v)[n-1], (*v)[r]);
1503  }
1504}


1615  shuffle(&load_list);
1616
1617  for (auto&& task : load_list) {
1618    if (!task->load()) {
1619      return false;
1620    }
1621  }
```

Comment: Randomising the addresses libraries are loaded at as a basic security measure.

Comment: Thanks，Is it because the address of the native library is not fixed due to random loading, which has an effect similar to ASLR?

Comment: I checked the Android security update announcement , and found that did join ASLR in Android 7.0 by randomizing the library load order. Thank you very much for your answer.